# Why does the code in my onclick event after a confirm not run?

Tags: javascript, onclick, confirm

Consider the following code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return confirm(&quot;sure to remove?&quot;);;

new Ajax.Updater('12', '/admin/files/remove/id/12', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:false});; 

return false;">Remove

</a>
```

It does not work, and I am not sure why.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing gets executed after a `return` statement. When you return, you return. That's what `return` is for. Thus no code after `return confirm(&quot;sure to remove?&quot;);` will ever run.

You probably want something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="
    if (confirm(&quot;sure to remove?&quot;)) {
        new Ajax.Updater('12', '/admin/files/remove/id/12', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:false});
    }
    return false;">Remove</a>
```

Although it would be much better to create a proper function and call that instead.